# Having trouble appending multiple nodes from JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm pulling contents from a tumblr site onto a webpage. Some of the working code is as follows:

```
var blogPull = jQ.getJSON("http://mysite.tumblr.com/api/read/json?num="+postQty+"&start="+offset+"&callback=?");

// Once the data has loaded...
blogPull.done( function( data ) {
    var items = jQ.map( data.posts, function( item ) {
        // If the post has multpile images
        if( item.type == 'photo' && item.photos.length > 0 ) {
            // Iterate and store them
            var imgs = jQ.map( item.photos, function( photo ){
                return jQ('<li class="blogPost"><img src="' + photo['photo-url-500'] + '" /></li>').get()
            });
            return imgs;
        };
    });
    $blogPosts.append(items);
});
```

However, if the post also has a caption, I would also like to include it after the image array has finished. I know that I can access it with `item['photo-caption']`, and I've tried a number of different ways, but I keep getting console errors.

To my mind, the following ought to work:

```
if( item.type == 'photo' && item.photos.length > 0 ) {
    var imgs = jQ.map( item.photos, function( photo ){
        return jQ('<li class="blogPost"><img src="' + photo['photo-url-500'] + '" /></li>').get()
    });
    var cptn = item['photo-caption'];
    return [imgs, cptn];
};
```

But in this instance I get the following error:

Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where is the exception exactly thrown? Have you stopped in the debugger and inspected the variables in the code?

Comment: The error appears in Chrome's console log (jquery.min.js:2). I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your second question - although I've a strong feeling I should.

Comment: When you open the chrome developer's tools (F12) you can go to sources, look for the file which has your script, set a breakpoint (clicking on the left gutter) and then, if you reload your page, the execution will stop at that point, and you can inspect variables, try expressions in the console and so on. You should read some tutorial on debugging in the browser (Chrome Developer's tools, Firebug in firefox...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I certainly will.